# PowerShell: Redirect output of a command line tool to the Host

Tags: powershell

I am trying to invoke a command-line .exe tool (`x264` to convert some videos) and print its output in PowerShell host.

There are a lot of parameters that need to be passed to the `x264`. So far I couldn't run it with the `Invoke-Item` cmdlet so I tried

```
[diagnostics.process]::start($com, $args).WaitForExit()
```

This works fine but it opens the old `cmd` window to show the output. Just out of curiosity I was wondering how can I show the output in the host.

Answer (score 2):

I might be completely off, no PowerShell guru, but can't you just run the following?

```
$args = @("list", "of", "args", "here")
& x264.exe $args
```

Answer (score 0):

When the cmd window opens, does it show the output? If so, maybe this can help.

```
Start-Process c:\x264.exe -ArgumentList $args -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: It outputs the result but not in the Host. (I removed the -NoNewWindow parameter to check) Also, is it possible to use this output?

Comment: I downloaded x264 (core:114 r1913 5fd3dce) and executed it, it runs in the same window. what happens when you assign the command to a variable? The variable contains the output when the program finished?

Comment: No, if I use a variable, it'll just print "True". I think that's the output for "0" (successfull exit).